# Function to refresh date every second eventually crashes Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, datetime, time

I have a few functions I use to get the date and time and then push those to elements in the DOM. It appears to be working great until after a few minutes the script drains chrome of memory and crashes the page. Here is the code I think affecting my problem:

```js
'use strict';

// ///////////////////////////// INITIAL /////////////////////////////////// //
function leading_0( num ) {
  if( num < 10 ) {
    num = '0' + num;
  }
  
  return num;
}

// ////////////////////////////// DATES //////////////////////////////////// //

function getCurrentTime( date ) {  // TIME / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / //
  var hours = date.getHours(),
      minutes = date.getMinutes(),
      seconds = date.getSeconds(),
      suffix = hours >= 12 ? 'PM' : 'AM',
      fullTime;

  hours = hours % 12;

  if( hours === 0 ){
    hours = 12;
  }

  minutes = leading_0( minutes );
  seconds = leading_0( seconds );
  fullTime = hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds + ' ' + suffix;

  return fullTime;
}  // \\/ / / / / / / / / / / / / / / TIME / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / //

function getYear( date ) {  /// / / / YEAR / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / //
  var year = date.getFullYear();

  return year;
}  // \\/ / / / / / / / / / / / / / / YEAR / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / //

function getMonthDay( date ) {  /// MONTH DAY / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / ///
  var day = date.getDate();

  return day;
}  // \\/ / / / / / / / / / / / / / MONTH DAY / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / ///

function getMonth( date ) {  // / / / MONTH / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / ///
  var months = [
    'January', 'Feburary', 'March',
    'April', 'May', 'June',
    'July', 'August', 'September',
    'October', 'November', 'December'
  ],
  month = months[ date.getMonth() ];

  return month;
}  // \\/ / / / / / / / / / / / / / / MONTH / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / ///

function getWkDay( date ) {  /// / / WEEK DAY / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / ///
  var weekdays = [ 
    'Sunday', 'Monday', 
    'Tueday', 'Wednesday', 
    'Thursday', 'Friday', 
    'Saturday' 
  ],
  wkDay = weekdays[ date.getDay() ];

  return wkDay;
}  // \\ / / / / / / / / / / / / / / WEEK DAY / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / ///

function callBySec( func ) {
  setInterval( func, 1000 );
}

function pushDate(){  /// / / / / / PUSH DATES / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / //
  var today = new Date(),
      wkDay,
      month,
      day,
      year,
      time,
      d = document;
    
  wkDay = getWkDay( today );
  month = getMonth( today );
  day = getMonthDay( today );
  year = getYear( today );
  time = getCurrentTime( today );
  
  d.getElementById( 'wkDay' ).textContent = wkDay;
  d.getElementById( 'month' ).textContent = month;
  d.getElementById( 'day' ).textContent = day;
  d.getElementById( 'year' ).textContent = year;
  d.getElementById( 'time' ).textContent = time;
  
  callBySec( pushDate );
}  // \\/ / / / / / / / / / / / / / PUSH DATES / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / //

// ////////////////////////////// START //////////////////////////////////// //
function start() {
  pushDate();
}
start();
```

```html
<p>
  <span id="wkDay"></span>, 
  <span id="month"></span> <span id="day"></span>, 
  <span id="year"></span> <b>|</b> <span id="time"></span>
</p>
```

Is the above code a major memory hog? Even on this SO page it eventually crashes chrome. Is there a better way to do this and get the same result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take out this line:

```
callBySec( pushDate );
```

at the end of `pushDate()`. You're already using `setInterval()` to call the function every second, you don't need to start the timer again. The result is that you're creating another timer every second. After a minute you're running the function 60 times every second.

Your code would be correct if `callBySec` used `setTimeout()` rather than `setInterval()`.

Then the `start()` function should call `callBySec`:

```js
'use strict';

function leading_0(num) {
  if (num < 10) {
    num = '0' + num;
  }

  return num;
}


function getCurrentTime(date) {
  var hours = date.getHours(),
    minutes = date.getMinutes(),
    seconds = date.getSeconds(),
    suffix = hours >= 12 ? 'PM' : 'AM',
    fullTime;

  hours = hours % 12;

  if (hours === 0) {
    hours = 12;
  }

  minutes = leading_0(minutes);
  seconds = leading_0(seconds);
  fullTime = hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds + ' ' + suffix;

  return fullTime;
} 

function getYear(date) {
  var year = date.getFullYear();

  return year;
} 

function getMonthDay(date) { 
  var day = date.getDate();

  return day;
} 

function getMonth(date) { 
  var months = [
      'January', 'Feburary', 'March',
      'April', 'May', 'June',
      'July', 'August', 'September',
      'October', 'November', 'December'
    ],
    month = months[date.getMonth()];

  return month;
} 
function getWkDay(date) { 
  var weekdays = [
      'Sunday', 'Monday',
      'Tueday', 'Wednesday',
      'Thursday', 'Friday',
      'Saturday'
    ],
    wkDay = weekdays[date.getDay()];

  return wkDay;
}

function callBySec(func) {
  setInterval(func, 1000);
}

function pushDate() { 
  var today = new Date(),
    wkDay,
    month,
    day,
    year,
    time,
    d = document;

  wkDay = getWkDay(today);
  month = getMonth(today);
  day = getMonthDay(today);
  year = getYear(today);
  time = getCurrentTime(today);

  d.getElementById('wkDay').textContent = wkDay;
  d.getElementById('month').textContent = month;
  d.getElementById('day').textContent = day;
  d.getElementById('year').textContent = year;
  d.getElementById('time').textContent = time;
} 

function start() {
  callBySec(pushDate);
}
start();
```

```html
<p>
  <span id="wkDay"></span>,
  <span id="month"></span> <span id="day"></span>,
  <span id="year"></span> <b>|</b> <span id="time"></span>
</p>
```

Comment: Great explanation. But you're still using `setInterval` which you recommended against.

Comment: @solacyon I didn't recommend against setInterval.

Comment: *"Your code would be correct if `callBySec` used `setTimeout()` rather than `setInterval()`"*

Comment: If you used `setTimeout`, then it would be correct to call it at the end of the function. But since you're using `setInterval`, it's not correct.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `setTimeout()` instead of `setInterval()` as the latter creates a recurring execution path while the former simply runs the code block once in a set time in the future.

As you have it, every second you are doubling the number of recurring executions of `pushDate()`.

Comment: But I do want an interval. Should I just loop `setTimeOut()`?

Answer (score 0):

I would completely expect this to OOM, as you are using recursion, and never break out.

The problem is that you end up with a call chain of

```
pushDate -> callBySec -> pushDate -> callBySec -> PushDate -> etc
```

Infinitely.

What you should do, is get rid of `callBySec` entirely, and change up your start method to use `setInterval` itself instead of relying on recursion ( you currently start a new timer every second ).

```
function start() {

    setInterval(pushDate, 1000);
}
```

Comment: This isn't recursion, because `setInterval()` runs the function asynchronously, not recursively.

Answer (score 0):

> The setInterval() method calls a function or evaluates an expression at specified intervals (in milliseconds).
>   The setInterval() method will continue calling the function until clearInterval() is called, or the window is closed.

Taken from https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

So, basically, you call your function `pushDate`, that starts a timer to call your function every second, and every called function starts another intervall.

If you call the intervall in your `start` function -  instead of recursive - it would be fine.